# Inline assembly isn't parsed properly

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I have this instruction:

```
asm("message: .byte 'Hello, World!', 0x0A");
```

For some reason the compiler says `junk at end of line, first recognized character is 'e'`. I tried replacing the `.byte` with `db` according to other examples on the web. Then the output was `no such instruction: 'db 72ello, World!440x0A'` (notice the numbers instead of the apostrophe). To me it seems like there is something wrong with the parsing of the `'`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `.byte` only works for a single byte, like 0xFA, or 'F'.
2. `db` is intel syntax, inline assembly uses GNU syntax.
3. As mentioned above, `.byte` only works for one byte. To use strings, use either `.ascii` or `.asciz` -- the former is a simple array of bytes, while the latter is null terminated.

ie. `asm("message: .asciz \"Hello, World!\n\"");`

Comment: It worked, Thanks! Do you have a reference where I can read about this kind of stuff?

Comment: A general guide would be the GNU as manual (man as?) Alternatively, visit the osdev wiki page on inline assembly.